# Using modelformset_factory and access attributes of an object

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, python-3.6

I have some `Container`s and they have a number of `Box`es I want to edit. So, naturally, I use [modelformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

It works very good:

```
container = get_object_or_404(Container, id=container_id)
BoxFormSet = modelformset_factory(Box, fields=('a', 'b', 'c'))
formset = BoxFormSet(queryset=container.box_set.all())
```

In my template I iterate over `formset` to show the boxes I want to modify.

This works very well and I can edit the attributes `a`, `b` and `c` of each `Box`. But each box has also a `label`. I want to access the value to show it in the label but it should not be editable, like an `input`-field. I just need the value. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I want only have the value. Not a TextInput-widget or something what renders automatically.

Comment: See my updated answer. Just accessing the value is fairly easy: `form.instance` gives you the model instance of each form.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `widgets` parameter to the factory. There you can specify the appropriate attribute for the label input:

```
BoxFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    Box, 
    fields=('a', 'b', 'c', 'label'),
    widgets={'label': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': True})}
)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want a auto-rendered, yet disabled input, you can just access the label in the template via the form's instance:

```
{% for form in box_formset %}
    # form stuff
    {{ form.instance.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend specifying a form to use for the model, and in that form you can set whatever attributes you want to read-only.

```
#forms.py
class BoxForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields=('a', 'b', 'c', 'label')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.id:
            self.fields['label'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

#views.py
BoxFormSet = modelformset_factory(Box, form=BoxForm)
```

An alternative would be to set those fields as read-only using javascript

```
$('input[name="label"]').attr('readonly', true);
```

Personally, I would prefer the first